# "key = value" lines: how to replace a specific key's value?

Tags: sed

I want to find the right hand side of an expression in a file and replace its value with something else using `sed`. With `grep`, we see

```
$ grep power TheFile 
power                 = 1
```

Also with `cut`, I can access the value

```
$ grep power TheFile  | cut -d = -f 2
 1
```

However, I don't know how to pipe that with the `sed` command. Any idea to accomplish that?

Comment: Is the "something else" a *function* of the existing value, or you just want to put some default string as the replacement?

Comment: No it is just an integer. For example, changing 1 to 2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
sed '/^power /s/=.*$/= your-replacement/' TheFile
```

1. `/^power /` is an address specifier, in this case looking for a line that matches a regex `^power`.
2. `s` is a replacement command, matching a regex being everything after the `=`.
3. Note that there is no need to pipe the contents of the file; you can just specify it (or a list of files) as a command argument. If you want / need to pipe something into `sed`, that's easy - just `| sed ..`.
4. If the whitespace immediately after the initial word (eg. `power`) might be a tab, use `[[:blank:]]` instead. Some versions of `sed` allow you to use `\t` for a definite tab character.

Comment: This would also modify lines that start with e.g. `power_output`.

Comment: And now, however unlikely, lines that start with `power output`... But that's nitpicking.

Answer (score 6):

To find the lines in `TheFile` that starts with the word `power` followed by some amount of whitespace and an equal sign, and to replace whatever comes after that equal sign with `something`:

```
sed -E 's/^(power[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*).*/\1something/' TheFile
```

`[[:blank:]]*` matches zero or more spaces or tabs. This preserves the whitespace before and after the `=`.  The `\1` in the replacement text will insert the part of the string that is matched by the first parenthesis.

To make the change in place with e.g. GNU `sed`, add the `-i` flag, otherwise, redirect the output to a new file.

Testing it:

```
$ cat TheFile
power                 = 1
power123              = 1
power  123            = 1
power                 =
power                 =                 112

$ sed -E 's/^(power[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*).*/\1something/' TheFile
power                 = something
power123              = 1
power  123            = 1
power                 =something
power                 =                 something
```