# What is the meaning of '\1' in the right-hand side of a sed substitution?

Tags: sed

I am posting this question because I am unable to add a comment to an answer submitted by Kusalananda here: ["key = value" lines: how to replace a specific key's value?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427291/key-value-lines-how-to-replace-a-specific-keys-value)

He proposed the following solution:

```
sed -E 's/^(power[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*).*/\1something/' TheFile
```

Q1: What is the meaning of "\1"?

Q2: How can I modify this when dealing with key-value pairs with quotations around the value? e.g.

```
MTU="1500"
```

--- edit ---

Q3: In trying the suggestion from RalfFriedl I discovered that the name of my variable is being inserted, not the value.

```
sed -E 's/^(MTU[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*).*/\1$NewMtu/' MyEthFile
```

Comment: I don't disagree that this is a duplicate question. My first problem was not being able to add a comment to the original solution I reference.

Comment: I have updated that answer to include what `\1` refers to.  For your second question, it is unclear what the issue is.  To insert `"150"`, use that string in place of `something`.

Comment: For your third question (not more than one question per question, please, and no follow-up question in the same question either, unless it's trivial), see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209971/is-there-any-way-to-print-value-inside-variable-inside-single-quote or any other question relating to expanding variables inside single quotes (which the shell does not do).

Comment: Don't wrap "MTU...=" in parenthesis; the parenthesis captures what you *want* in `\1`, so start after the equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `\1` is that is inserts the value of the first parenthesis, in this case everything between `(power[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*)`

For your second question, you could use a pattern of `MTU="(.*)"` and replace it with `\1` to get `1500`.

Comment: I might suggest `([^"]*)` so that you don't accidentally grab more than desired

Comment: RalfFriedl: It's not clear to me how you proposed answer for Q2 would deal with whitespace around the equal sign. That is the advantage of the form used by Kusalananda.

Comment: @aenagy It would not, because your question didn't mention white space. It seems you already know enough about regular expressions, just not about using the replacement reference.